# CakePHP SoapClient drops fields?

Tags: php, cakephp, soap, cakephp-2.0, soap-client

My app uses CakePHP (2.2.5) to get data from a SOAP server.  I put logging into the SoapSource.php connector to see the XML returned and to display the array returned:

```
$result = $this->client->__soapCall($method, array('parameters' => $tParams));
Logger::write('SOAP Last Response', $this->client->__getLastResponse(), 3, 'transaction');
Logger::write('SOAP Last Response Object', print_r($result, TRUE), 3, 'transaction');
```

But what I'm seeing in the log is that two (recently-added) fields present in the XML are **missing** from the array, specifically, the last two before the RPList (formatted here but otherwise verbatim):

```
<transactionResult>
  <id>test</id>
  <resultCode>0</resultCode>
  <ReadScheduledRecordingsRsp>
    <RecordingDefinitionList>
      <RecordingDefinition>
        <RDId>d8c16d8f-67c6-469a-83c3-d51d8f8859a9</RDId>
        <Title>The Young and the Restless</Title>
        <SeriesId>4422</SeriesId>
        <KeepUntil>SpaceIsNeeded</KeepUntil>
        <StartPadSeconds>0</StartPadSeconds>
        <EndPadSeconds>0</EndPadSeconds>
        <Frequency>EveryDay</Frequency>
        <KeepAtMost>0</KeepAtMost>
        <Priority>23</Priority>
        <ShowType>Any</ShowType>
        <AirtimeDomain>SpecificTime</AirtimeDomain>
        <ChannelDomain>SpecificChannel</ChannelDomain>
        <RPList>
          ...
```

Followed by:

```
ARRAY
 (
  [transactionResult] => stdClass Object
   (
    [id] => test
    [resultCode] => 0
    [ReadScheduledRecordingsRsp] => stdClass Object
     (
      [RecordingDefinitionList] => stdClass Object
       (
        [RecordingDefinition] => Array
         (
           [0] => stdClass Object
            (
             [RDId] => d8c16d8f-67c6-469a-83c3-d51d8f8859a9
             [Title] => The Young and the Restless
             [SeriesId] => 4422
             [KeepUntil] => SpaceIsNeeded
             [StartPadSeconds] => 0
             [EndPadSeconds] => 0
             [Frequency] => EveryDay
             [KeepAtMost] => 0
             [Priority] => 23
             [ShowType] => Any
             [RPList] => stdClass Object
              (
              ...
```

I'm guessing I just forgot or didn't know to do something, but I don't know what.  It's just very suspicious that the two fields that don't work are the two that were just added, but I can't find any place where the fields are enumerated.

The WSDL doesn't specify any fields at all, just that there will be a bunch of data inside a transactionResult.

In the connect call, the options likewise don't specify any fields.

It all worked fine until the back-end added those two fields, and it all *still* works fine, except that I can't see the 2 new fields in the object.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also, I forgot to add, the $tparams used in the soapCall also don't mention any fields.

Comment: Tried restarting Apache while deleting Cake's tmp/cache, also with no effect.

Comment: I added a (really nasty) work-around that uses xml_parse_into_struct() to extract the two missing fields' values from the XML, and insert them into the resulting object, and that works fine.  So it seems the problem is not an error in the original XML, since it's parseable.  I'm hoping the bounty will attract an answer that will allow me to eliminate the work-around.

Comment: Did you tried setting `'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE` in the soapclient definition?

Comment: What Nunser is saying.  Try adding the directive  `ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);` before the SOAP calls or pass this array as the second argument of your SoapClient objects ctor `array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE)`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see the XML for RPList.  What version of PHP/libxml?

Have you actually [validated](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/) the XML returned by __getLastResponse()?

It sounds to me like your using WSDL mode for the client but your WSDL file lacks precision.  Try using a WSDL which actually describes the data being served up by the API.

Am I understanding that the $result object when dumped lists `RPList` but the value is not what you expect?  If so you might be able to get away with adding the `SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS` option to the clients constructor: `new SoapClient($wsdl, array('features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS));`.  That's a long shot though.  Need to see WSDL and full output from `__getLastResponse()`.

Any errors?  Try wrapping the call like so:

```
try {

  $client = new SoapClient ('http://yoursite.com?WSDL', 
    array("trace" => 1,
      "exceptions" => true,
      "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
      "features" => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS)
  );

  $result = $client->SomeMethod($data);

} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
  var_dump($exception);
} catch (Exception $exception) {
  var_dump($exception);
}
```

Short of fixing the WSDL/XML response your workaround seems like the best solution.

Comment: The problem is right BEFORE the RPList: the XML has 2 fields (AirtimeDomain, ChannelDomain) that are absent from the struct.
<br><br>
The WSDL is provided by the server which I don't control.  The data is highly variable, and not specified by the WSDL.  
<br><br>
I have not validated the XML, though xml_parse_into_struct() IS able to parse it.  If it doesn't validate, there's realistically nothing I can do about it.  
<br><br>
If there were an exception in a place where I don't catch it, there's a top-level exception handler that would at least tell me that one occurred, which doesn't happen.

Comment: Oh, and SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS is already in use.  (All kinds of things don't work right without it in this context.)

Comment: Oh, I missed that it was those two basic fields that were absent. Still, sounds like bad WSDL. Remove it from the equation and try to use the client in non-WSDL mode perhaps?  Sounds like you gain nothing from using the WSDL now anyway.  Also double check its throwing SoapFaults, try and cause one and make sure you are in fact catching them.  Would stink if there were more info out there you were missing.